# i am getting error in installing botframework emulator in windows 7 32 bit

Tags: c#, .net

[I downloaded .exe file of bot framework and after half installation it was failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4mxt.png)

Comment: Have a look at the setup logfile, as suggested by the popup.

Comment: what i have to look?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 32bit install for the emulator right now.  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/202